# How to get the end screen element with an end_screen_element_id from Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

With a [channel reporting job](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports#video-end-screens), we can get the end_screen_element_ids for a given video. These IDs look like GUIDs.

The question is : How do we query the Youtube API to get what video/channel/... these end_screen_element_ids points to ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`reportTypes.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/reportTypes/list#id) method. This returns a list of report types that the channel or content owner can retrieve. Each item in the list contains an `id` property, which identifies the report's ID, and you need this value to schedule a reporting job.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My question might be misleading; I've already created the reporting job for end screens. In the report, I get the end_screen_element_type, some stats, and the end_screen_element_id. What I'am after is a way to link the end_screen_element_id with a video, channel, playlist. Basically, I want to find out what is behind the end screen element. Do you know how to do this?